# Program "g++" not found in PATH on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, g++

I have eclipse Luna installed on Ubuntu with no internet connection.
I tried to run the simple "Hello World" program but I encountered the error:

> Program "g++" not found in PATH

I downloaded (on another computer and copied it) the `g++_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_i386.deb` and tried to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i g++_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

and I got this error message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++:i386:
g++:i386 depends on cpp (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6)
g++:i386 depends on gcc (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6)
g++:i386 depends on g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~)
g++:i386 depends on gcc-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~)

dpkg: error processing g++:i386 (--install)
```

How can I install that `g++` properly with no internet connection?
I will be happy for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect your computer to internet and update the OS.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Then Try to install g++

Answer (score 0):

You could use apt-offline. You'll need to download and install the deb file using:

```
dpkg -i apt-offline_1.3.1_all.deb
```

This program will download dependencies on an online machine, ready for you to copy across to install on your offline machine. 
[Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_apt-offline) a link on how to use it.